# how to add back ground image to navigation controller root view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

i want to add bg image to root view so that it will be visible in all views ....

Answer (score 2):

Have a `UIImageView` behind the navigation controller. Then make the background for the visible view controller of the navigation controller transparent.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using transparency -- make a custom subclass of UIView that you use for your views that go get the background image of the root view.  If you make the views transparent, they will look different during animation (slide in/out) than they would if you repeat the image in each view.

Answer (score 0):

i have added image to window in IB of rootview controller that solved my problem